# Missing wp-load.php on new install

Tags: installation

I am technically proficient, but am new to administering a wordpress site.

I have a basic wordpress site for which I simply do some blogging, no plugins. I have exported the data using the myphpadmin in cpanel. I nuked the site and create a new one through the installer. I then reloaded all of the data through the SQL interface.

Now when I navigate to www.forerunnerintl.org/blog I get:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/forerunn/public_html/blog/wp-load.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/forerunn/public_html/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 13

Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/forerunn/public_html/blog/wp-load.php' (include_path='.:/opt/php54/lib/php') in /home/forerunn/public_html/blog/wp-blog-header.php on line 13
```

I looked and that file is not there, but I have no idea how to create it.

Comment: If you have FTP access, you should consider downloading a fresh install from wordpress.org and uploading that fresh install over the top.  That's what I'd try, at least.

Comment: As @socki03 said, you only really need to copy the wp-content folder as that's where the customization starts. Everything outside of that you should download fresh from WordPress and that should solve your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As socki03 suggested, I downloaded and upload a fresh install and things are now limping along a bit. I'm posting the configuration issue I'm having in another question.

Thanks for the help.